# How to create a node that can control the model through arrow keys?

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, now I create a model in gazebo and wanna control it through arrow keys. To put it simple, I want to write a program that works as  `rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key`, but on my custom topic `cambot/cmd_vel`. How can I get the source code of `turtle_teleop_key`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286821/how-to-create-a-node-that-can-control-the-model-through-arrow-keys?/) by [stefanvan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33959/stefanvan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would recommend to use [teleop_twist_keyboard](http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_keyboard) for this. No need to write anything yourself (it already publishes `Twist`s to `cmd_vel`, so just `remap`), but if you really want to, see [ros-teleop/teleop_twist_keyboard](https://github.com/ros-teleop/teleop_twist_keyboard) for the source.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stefanvan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33959/stefanvan/) on 2018-03-28**:
Thank you so much, sir. The first method you recommend solves my problem.